# How to get the Google AppEngine test framework example working on Python 2.7?

Tags: unit-testing, google-app-engine, python-2.7

In my project I've been using the Google test framework example, at the bottom of: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/localunittesting

This has been working fine in Python2.5, but now with Python 2.7 (is my default python version) It's not picking up the Python 2.7 libraries.

The test are still executed, but with the Python 2.5 runtime and not with Python 2.7

Examples:
- It's using the default 0.96 django library
- It can find the module json when using import json (that works fine in production)

Does anybody know how to run unit tests that do use the Python 2.7 AppEngine SDK?

Comment: Can you check file location via `json.__file__` of the `json` library you are importing? Assert that the path is correct and share your findings.

Answer (score 0):

When I went from python2.5 to python2.7, I had to update the path to my python binary in the GoogleAppEngineLauncher preferences window (GAEL -> Preferences). Did you do that?